# "@/path/to/a/file" in PHP, what does it mean?

Tags: php, string, filepath

I have stumbled to following code example:

```
$image = 'file/path';
$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
  array(
    'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
    'status'   => "Don't slip up" // Don't give up..
  ),
  true, // use auth
  true  // multipart
);
```

The confusing bit is "@{$image}", what that "at" sign does in front of the file path?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what library you're using, but I assume it uses the [PHP cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension internally, because that's how you specify to cURL the path to a file that you want to upload, i.e., by prepending the path with an `@`. See this [example from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#example-4800):

```
<?php

/* http://localhost/upload.php:
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
*/

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code in the question, the '@' sign is just part of a string variable. It has no special meaning to PHP as a language.

It might have special meaning to the code which it is being passed to, but it isn't anything to PHP other than a simple string variable that happens to start with an '@' sign.

From the context, I guess presumably it's being passed to Twitter as part of a JSON object. In that case, it might have a special meaning to Twitter, but I don't know the API, so I couldn't tell you that for certain. In any case, it's not a PHP question.

Answer (score 2):

The `{$expression}` syntax is one way to [embed a variable or expression in a string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) in PHP, like the `#{expression}` syntax in Ruby.

So `"@{$image}"` is equivalent to `'@'.$image`.

The `@` is used by the [curl module](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) to differenciate a regular POST variable value from a filename to upload. Your library must use the curl module internally or follow the same conventions.

When setting POST variables, if any value is prefixed with an `@`, it is considered to be a filename to upload:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'regular_variable' => 'value',
    'some_file' => '@/path/to/filename', // this is treated as a file to upload
));
```

This is not very well known and can lead to security issues if the programmer is not aware of this. This can be *disabled* by passing a query-string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ([http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query)).

This has no special meaning for PHP itself.

Comment: Good to know that '@...' can be worked arround using http_build_query(), if it is not meant as a file upload! Thanks!